# Is it possible to extract mass concentration from DLS measurement?

Tags: concentration

DLS (dynamic light scattering) gives the particle size distribution (number percent vs. size) of particles in suspension. It also gives the count rate (cps, counts per second).

Knowing this and the physical properties of the dispersing medium and particles, is it possible to extract the mass concentration of the particles?